# can I submit an iOS app with self signed SSL certificate?

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, https, submission

I have an app connecting via https where the web server has a self signed SSL. Is this allowed by apple or does anything have to be done before submission?

Comment: the self-singed certificates may need to be **marked as trusted manually** by the end-user in the iOS Settings app – iOS will not trust self-signed certificates automatically, but the end-user could override that case by case, so, that is nothing to do with the submission or approval.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it, you can find the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

You need to define in your info.plist your domain.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```